# Try to get the cross of 2 series of a pandas table

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am stuck with an issue on a massive pandas table. I would like to get a boolean to check the cross of 2 series.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': [10, 1, 2, 8]})
```

I would like to add one column in my array to get a result like this one

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': [10, 1, 2, 8],
                   'C': [0, -1, 0, 1]
                  })
```

So basically to get
0 when there is no cross between series B and A
-1 when table B crosses down table A
1 when table B crosses up table A

I need to do vector calculation because my real table is like more than one million rows.

Thank you

Comment: Those are lists, not dataframes. Please put in the effort to provide the correct datastructures, then we'll put in the effort trying to help you.

Comment: Hi 7Bridges, could you provide a minimal reproducible example? See here; https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the relative position of the 2 columns with `lt`, then convert to integer and compute the `diff`:

```
m = df['A'].lt(df['B'])
df['C'] = m.astype(int).diff().fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

output:

```
   A   B  C
0  1  10  0
1  2   1 -1
2  3   2  0
3  4   8  1
```

visual of A/B:

[image]